# Thread vs Threadstart

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In C#, practically, I haven't observed any difference between the following:

```
new Thread(SomeMethod).Start();
```

,

```
new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SomeMethod));
```

and

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(SomeMethod));
```

What is the difference, if there is any at all?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The `Thread(ThreadStart)` constructor can only be used when the signature of your `SomeMethod` method matches the `ThreadStart` delegate. Conversely, `Thread(ParameterizedThreadStart)` requires `SomeMethod` to match the `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate. The signatures are below:

```
public delegate void ThreadStart()
public delegate void ParameterizedThreadStart(Object obj)
```

Concretely, this means that you should use `ThreadStart` when your method does not take any parameters, and `ParameterizedThreadStart` when it takes a single `Object` parameter. Threads created with the former should be started by calling `Start()`, whilst threads created with the latter should have their argument specified through `Start(Object)`.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var threadA = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ExecuteA));
    threadA.Start();

    var threadB = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ExecuteB));
    threadB.Start("abc");

    threadA.Join();
    threadB.Join();
}

private static void ExecuteA()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Executing parameterless thread!");
}

private static void ExecuteB(Object obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Executing thread with parameter \"{obj}\"!");
}
```

Finally, you can call the `Thread` constructors without specifying the `ThreadStart` or `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate. In this case, the compiler will match your method to the constructor overload based on its signature, performing the cast implicitly.

```
var threadA = new Thread(ExecuteA);   // implicit cast to ThreadStart
threadA.Start();

var threadB = new Thread(ExecuteB);   // implicit cast to ParameterizedThreadStart
threadB.Start("abc");
```

Answer (score 11):

#### `new Thread(SomeMethod)` and `new Thread(new ThreadStart(SomeMethod))`:

The difference between `new Thread(SomeMethod)` and `new Thread(new ThreadStart(SomeMethod))` is purely syntactical: The C# compiler generates the same code for these; the former version is an abbreviation of the latter.

(The compiler can automatically deduce the proper delegate type to use from the signatures of the available `Thread` constructors, and the signature of the specified method `SomeMethod`. Writing out `new ThreadStart(…)` instead of just `…` is a little bit like replacing `var` with the actual type of some expression, you're sparing the compiler the work of figuring out the actual type.)

These two versions work when `SomeMethod` takes no parameters, because that's the signature required to match the `ThreadStart` delegate.

#### `new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SomeMethod))`:

The difference between the above two and `new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SomeMethod))` is that this one is calling a different constructor on `Thread`.

And that `ParameterizedThreadStart` proscribes a different method signature than `ThreadStart`: Your `SomeMethod` needs to take one argument of type `object`, otherwise it does not match this delegate type.

Answer (score 2):

No, but there are a lot of times when your code look a lot nicer if you create the ThreadStart object in one place and starts the new thread in another place.